# What is the difference?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I would like to make an `count` to  count the users which are in tlp but not in gal for this I have the next code :

```
select count(*) 
from tlp
where ((not EXISTS (SELECT mail 
                    FROM glob
                    WHERE tlp.email1 = glob.mail) 
        AND tlp.email1 IS NOT NULl)
         or ( not EXISTS (SELECT LOGIN
                         FROM   glob 
                         WHERE  tlp.userid = glob.LOGIN     
                        ) 
                        and tlp.email1 is null));
```

When I run this I received 688 users and when I want to  remove that users with this code :

```
Delete from tlp
  where (( not EXISTS (SELECT mail 
                     FROM   glob 
                     WHERE    tlp.email1 = glob.mail  ) 
         AND tlp.email1 IS NOT NULl)
         or ( not EXISTS (SELECT Login 
                         FROM   glob 
                         WHERE  tlp.userid = glob.login    
                        ) 
                        and tlp.email1 is null));
```

I have 672  deleted rows.
I can't see the problem

Comment: Could the data just have changed between the select and the delete? Is this reproducible?

Answer (score 0):

This approach is simpler

```
select count(*) from 
(
select idField
from etc -- 
minus
select idField
from etc -- these are the records you want to exclude
) derivedTable
```

You can work out the details.